# Scala Type Safety with Tinkerpop Frames

Tags: scala, tinkerpop, tinkerpop-frames

**How can I use the type safety of Scala with Tinkerpop Frames' annotations?**

This is the Java version example at https://github.com/tinkerpop/frames/wiki :

```
public interface Person {
  @Property("name")
  public String getName();

  @Adjacency(label="knows")
  public Iterable<Person> getKnowsPeople();

  @Adjacency(label="knows")
  public void addKnowsPerson(final Person person);

  @GremlinGroovy("it.out('knows').out('knows').dedup") //Make sure you use the GremlinGroovy module! #1
  public Iterable<Person> getFriendsOfAFriend()
}
```

The Property and Adjacency are simple enough.

**But the traversal function is contained within a String so that Scala's type system cannot help.**

I am using Gremlin-Scala (https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala) to construct my traversals in Scala syntax.  Maybe it can be used to further a solution.